# Upgrade from 2012 Standard to 2019 Essentials

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2019, upgrade

We have a client running a very old physical server running 2012 Standard.  We want to upgrade to 2019 essentials.  We want to switch to essentials since they will not need more than 25 cals.  Is there any way to do an in-place install (even in multiple steps) so we do not have to re-install all of the software?  I have tried some different approaches but the option to keep current files is always disabled.

Comment: **I have tried some different approaches but the option to keep current files is always disabled.** - Maybe you could tell us what you've tried so that we don't have to guess.

Comment: as told down below you have to upgrade any version between them, you csnt skip any

Answer (score 2):

If this server is running 2012 Standard, rather than 2012R2, then there isn't an in-place upgrade path to Server 2019.

> Windows Server can typically be upgraded through at least one, and sometimes even two, versions. For example, Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows Server 2016 can both be upgraded in-place to Windows Server 2019.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/upgrade/upgrade-overview

Comment: you can try to upgrade to r2 and any version between them, then it might be possible

Comment: I know that I need to potentially upgrade in stages to get to 2019.  My question is how can I get from 2012 Standard to Essentials.  The client has had the server for 10+ years and was installed by a previous IT consultant.  We are looking for the easiest way to move them to Essentials to save money on cals.  They will never need more than the 25 that come with it.  Also, should I be running the upgrade install from the existing OS or booted from the iso media?  I have always done upgrade installs from the OS.